# Classes and subclass

Tags: java

I am struggling to figure how how to get my two sub classes in order for my first                                      subclass i want to add the attributes color of car and speed. so far i have

```
public class ColorSpeed extends Vehicle {      

public int Truck;
public int Sedan;
public int SportsCar;
public ColorSpeed(int Truck,
int Sedan,
int SportsCar,{
super(Truck, Sedan, SportsCar);
CarSpeed = "60";
}   


public void CarSpeed, CarType(int newValue){

CarType = newValue;
CarSpeed = newValue;
CarColor = newValue;
}   
}
```

for the next subclass i need to add the two types of fuel regular and preimum. i have

```
public class fuel extends ColorSpeed {


    public int Regular;
    public int premium;


    public ColorSpeed(int NumWheels,
                      int NumPassengers,
                      int TypeFuel,
    {
        super(NumWheels, NumPassengers, TypeFuel);
        CarSpeed = "60";
    }   


    public void Regular, Premium(int newValue){

        Regular = new Integer(2.00);  
        Premium = new Integer(3.00); 
    }   
}
```

and my main class has these methods:

Vehicle class

- Constructor methods

  - No-argument constructor that requests all attribute information from the user and then           builds a Vehicle object.
- Accessor methods

  - getNumWheels() – returns int number of wheels
  - getNumPassengers() – returns int number of passsengers (including the driver)
  - getTypeFuel() – returns as a String the fuel the vehicle was designed for
- Mutator methods

  - setNumWheels(int) – sets the number of wheels for the vehicle
  - setNumPassengers(int) – sets the number of passengers (including the driver) for the    vehicle
  - setTypeFuel(String) – sets the fuel the vehicle was designed for

I am very new and really would like to learn and would love any help at all!!

Comment: This isn't Java. Can you post some compileable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very good way to use inheritance.

A subclass should only be created if the object it represents is a "special case" of its superclass.

The more easily understandable case in this area is `Vehicle`, extended by `PassengerCar`, `PickupTruck`, `SemiRig`, and `Bus`.  All these subclasses are special cases of their superclass.  The Vehicle can have attributes that are the same attributes (with different values) of things like length, height, weight, turningRadius, etc., but the subclasses can exhibit different behavior for their special cases.

Comment: @user2958835: A typical way you'd see this taught is that a subclass is an "is a" relationship. As a general guideline, if "A is a B" then it makes sense to have A be a subclass of B. Do these make sense: ColorSpeed is a Vehicle? fuel is a ColorSpeed? fuel is a Vehicle?

Comment: OK I get you and see what I should of done. i should add a subclass that has relativity to my main class, like types of vehicle. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: It's a little more than being related to your main class.  In good OO design, the subclass represents an object that is one of a set of things that represent a more general object represented by the superclass.  It is also traditional to 'accept' stackoverflow answers if they are the best help you received for a given question; the points awarded people flow that way, and you are recognized as a question-asker who marks the best answer, and are therefore more liable to have future questions answered.